# Increment Record based on field

Tags: class, quote

I'd like to increment fields based on the quote field, so when a quote is created, a custom field will increment depend on the region (each field will have format of "ZO - {000}). Each region should have it's own series of Unique numbers.
For example: if it's a "US" region quote, "Quote Number1" custom field will increment (. If it's a "ROW" region quote, "Quote Number2" custom field will increment.

Standard "Autonumber" field works on any record creation, and not customized by record types..

UPDATE: I modified a trigger posted as an answer (@user2590, see below your modified code). I want the autonumbers to work only for "Invoice" record type in Quotes ("Quote record type should be affected"). I assume it is simpler than the original code but somehow it doesn't work...I'm getting: "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object". Can you have a look and see what's not working?

```
trigger SampleAutoNumberRegion on Quote (before insert){
String[] name = new String[]{'Invoice'};

Map<Id, RecordType> regions = new Map<Id,RecordType>([SELECT Name from RecordType WHERE sObjectType = 'Quote' AND Name IN :name]);

AggregateResult res = [SELECT MAX(US_Invoice__c) max1, MAX(ROW_Invoice__c) max2 FROM Quote WHERE RecordType.Name IN :name ];


Integer max1 = Integer.valueOf(((String)res.get('max1')).substringAfter('- ') );
Integer max2 = Integer.valueOf(((String)res.get('max2')).substringAfter('- ') );


for(Quote theQuote : trigger.new){    


   if(thequote.Opportunity.Account.Region__c.contains('US')){   //region corresponds to 'US'
        String num1 = String.valueOf( (max1 != null) ? ++max1 : 1 );//will use the incremented value of max unless max was null (else use 1 instead)

        for(Integer i=0; i< (3 - num1.length() ); i++){ //should pad with leading zeros to ensure format of {000}
            num1 = '0' + num1;
        }
        theQuote.US_Invoice__c = 'ZO - ' + num1;

    }

     else if(!thequote.Opportunity.Account.Region__c.contains('US')) {

        String num2 = String.valueOf( (max2 != null) ? ++max2 : 1 );
        for(Integer i=0; i< (3 - num2.length() ); i++){ //should pad with leading zeros to ensure format of {000}
            num2 = '0' + num2;
        }
        theQuote.ROW_Invoice__c = 'ZO - ' + num2;
   }

}
}
```

Comment: Create a Custom Setting potentially, with fields per Region and have values in them. Have a utility class to read values from the custom setting, which increments the value and sets to the custom setting, so that the next number in the sequence is available to subsequent requests.

Comment: Itay: I think you're basically asking the same thing as this question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4289/generating-a-guaranteed-contiguous-series-of-numbers/4296#4296

Comment: You're getting a Null Pointer Exception because you are trying to refer to a related object based on a triggered record. `thequote.Opportunity.Account.Region__c` will return null, and therefore .contains() throws an exception. You will need to query the database to get the Region__c value from the Account, and then use the queried value to determine the region to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated to include sample code**
You should be able to use a trigger on Quote, acting before insert (and maybe update as well, depending on your needs).

I assume that your recordtype's name corresponds to the region.

```
trigger Sample on Quote (before insert){
String[] names = new String[]{'US','ROW'};
Map<Id, RecordType> regions = new Map<Id,RecordType>([SELECT Name from RecordType WHERE sObjectType = Quote AND Name IN :names]);
AggregateResult res = [SELECT MAX(Quote_Number1__c) max1, MAX(Quote_Number2__c) max2 FROM Quote WHERE RecordType.Name IN :names];
Integer max1 = Integer.valueOf(((String)res.get('max1')).right(3) );
Integer max2 = Integer.valueOf(((String)res.get('max2')).right(3) );

for(Quote theQuote : trigger.new){

    if( regions.get(theQuote.RecordTypeId).Name == 'US'){   //region corresponds to 'US'
        String num1 = String.valueOf( (max1 != null) ? ++max1 : 1 );//will use the incremented value of max unless max was null (else use 1 instead)
        for(Integer i=0; i< (3 - num1.length() ); i++){ //should pad with leading zeros to ensure format of {000}
            num1 = '0' + num1;
        }
        theQuote.Quote_Number1__c = 'ZO - ' + num;
    }else if( regions.get(theQuote.RecordTypeId).Name == 'ROW'){    //region corresponds to 'ROW' 
        String num2 = String.valueOf( (max2 != null) ? ++max2 : 1 );
        for(Integer i=0; i< (3 - num2.length() ); i++){ //should pad with leading zeros to ensure format of {000}
            num2 = '0' + num2;
        }
        theQuote.Quote_Number2__c = 'ZO - ' + num;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: We have two business units that need different and consistent Quote numbers ("US Quote Number" and "ROW Quote Number"). can you display a sample trigger?

Comment: okay, I'll write up a sample and update in a moment

Comment: Sorry, that one actually isn't bulk safe. Updating again :)

Comment: This one is clean. Let me know if that helps

Comment: Thanks @user2590! The recordtype name doesn't corresponds to the region (sorry for not making it clear...). I have two record types on Quotes - "Quote" and "Invoice". I want this to apply only to "Invoice". "Region" is just a field on quotes (it is derived from a custom field called "region" on accounts)

Comment: Ahh, well I think my example should be easy enough to adapt for that. Does it hit your use-case?

Comment: I will publish the code I modified..

Comment: Where is the nullpointer happening? I'm thinking it may be due to your referencing up through parent relationships without having queried for those fields. EX: theQuote.Opportunity.Account.Region__c.contains('US'). I believe that the trigger context only holds the fields of the quote itself, and not these relationship values. You may need to build a queried map for these relation fields  with the quote IDs as the keys (like I did up top with the record types)

Comment: such as: Map<Id,Quote> quotes = new Map<Id,Quote>([SELECT Opportunity.Account.Region__c FROM Quote WHERE Id IN :quoteIds]);

Comment: Did this resolve your issue @ItayB?

Answer (score 1):

Food for thought, if Region was promoted to a custom object, then the number could be generated declaratively. Worth testing the deletion case behaves is as you expect.

*Region* object:

- Field QuoteCount__c is a Roll-Up Summary (MAX Quote Sequence__c)

*Quote* object:

- Field Region__c is a Master-Detail(Region)
- Field Sequence__c is a Number
- SequenceIncrement is a Workflow Rule creating Sequence__c with Region__r.QuoteCount__c + 1