# How to generate the unique number for a record

Tags: salesforce-id

I have to generate a Unique number for every record in a object.I can't use the Auto-number and SFDC ID of the record.

It's a kind of External ID that external System can use to identify the records.

Comment: Can you explain why you can't add just an extra auto-number field to do this? That is by far the simplest solution.

Comment: is there some particular format that the external id must adhere to?

Comment: Do you care if they're in order? Or just that they're unique?

Comment: Similar question/answer can be found here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4289/generating-a-guaranteed-contiguous-series-of-numbers/4296#4296

Comment: @jjbennett530 Numbers with no gaps - the focus of your link - is extra hard; unclear yet whether that is required or not.

Answer (score 3):

If you really, really need to do this, you could try this:

```
String s = record.createDateTime.format(); // or some other datetime

Blob hash = Crypto.generateDigest('MD5', Blob.valueOf(s));
String uniqueString = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(hash);

return uniqueString;
```

You'd need to use it in an `oncreate` trigger and update the record with this value.
If the string was too long, you could just chop it off at some point using `theString.substring(start,numChars);`

Comment: I have a similar problem, with the parallel concurrence in the creation of of a custom setting record. Has been violated the the unique name rule and has been created two records with same name, which create problems in update etc...

Answer (score 3):

Elaborating on Caspar Harmer's answer:

`Blob hash = Crypto.generateDigest('MD5', Blob.valueOf(s));` is very expensive CPU Time wise.

The following test timed out for me, as did a loop of 1000:

```
@isTest
private static void testIdUniquenessMultipleCalls  () {
    Set<String> ids = new Set<string>();
    for(Integer i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        ids.add(Utility.getUniqueId());
    }
    system.assertEquals(10000,ids.size(),'consecutive calls must produce distinct Ids');
}
```

I always received a CPU Time Limit exception.

Here's a version that passes the test:

```
public static String getUniqueId(){
    String milliseconds = String.ValueOf(System.Now().getTime()); //unix timestamp
    Blob pseudoHash = Blob.ValueOf(milliseconds + String.ValueOf(Crypto.getRandomInteger()));
    String uniqueString = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(pseudoHash);
    uniqueString = uniqueString.length() > 255 ? uniqueString.substring(0,255) : uniqueString;
    return uniqueString;
}
```

Comment: If I grab the first 18 chars of <uniqueString>, as you might do for an external ID field and run it in a loop, I see duplicates. This doesn't happen when I use Crypto.generateAesKey() and convert to hex.